# how to automate kill PIDs to solve `Could not claim the USB device`?

Tags: usb, webcam, gphoto2

I have the same problem in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993876/gphoto2-could-not-claim-the-usb-device), but the problem is I want to automate this process in an executable file, without the need to kill first PIDs every time.
in fact, I want my executable file to detect these PIDs each time, and then kill them if necessary.

Do you have any idea how to do so?

Comment: Probably best to clarify your problem in its entirety rather than just post a link to a similar problem - it'll be easier for people to see what your issue is without having to visit more than one page.

Answer (score 0):

Bash script I wrote for me when I had this problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
kill_args=$(pgrep gphoto)
  if [-z  $kill_args]; then

    echo "Arguments are:: $( pgrep gphoto )"
    pgrep gphoto | xargs kill
  else
    echo "No gphoto process"
  fi
```

This script Kills all active gphoto processes. I am uncertain if that will help in you bcase.